# I want to change the main content dynamically with javascript instead of individual pages

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

My website is currently using .tpl template files to load different pages dynamically. That will load an entire page again, so header, sidebar (chat), main content and the footer.

In my index.php file there is a switch case which loads the page 'home' when you click on 'home' in the menu. (example)

But I don't want that. Because their is also a chat in the sidebar, and that reloads/resets eveytime you load a different page. So all previous messages will be gone. So what I do want is changing only the main content part. So header, sidebar and footer will stay and won't reload.

I tried to do it with javascript but that didn't work...
Can someone help me or atleast put me on the right path?

(And yes, I have been searching for the last hour on stackoverflow and google but couldn't find anything...)

Comment: Perhaps you're looking out for [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application)

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue which can be answered in a few paragraphs. I would suggest you find a development forum (perhaps [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: Even if your pages are rendered from tpls there will still need to be a request to the backend which will reload the whole page. Easy answer: iframes (but please don't). You'll need something that fetches content asynchronously, via JavaScript. For really serious apps consider  https://angularjs.org/ or similar, but this could be overkill for you.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow following instruction :

1. Create separate .tpl file for header,footer,sidebar and contents files.
2. In main file include header,footer,sidebar and left one section for content.
   3.Replace your .tpl (using id or class) file content using ajax call.
3. bind your url with function.

   Sample code as below:

   // sidebar.php

   ```
       <ul>
       <li><a onclick="changePage(this)" data-page="home.tpl">Home</a></li>
       <li><a onclick="changePage(this)" data-page="aboutus.tpl">About Us</a></li>
       </ul>
   ```

   // master.php

   ```
        <?php 
              include("header.php");
              include("sidebar.php");
             ?>
              <section id="fileContent">
              </section>
           <?php   include("footer.php");
            ?>
   <script href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <script>
            function changePage(obj)
            {
               var Filename=$(obj).data('page')
               $.get(Filename, function( data ) {
                  $( "#fileContent" ).html(data);
                });
            }
       </script>
   ```

Comment: Well the sidebar is actually a chat on my website. So the menu you have in the 'sidebar.php' should be in the 'header.php' for me, i guess. 
And can you explain why in the Anchors there is (this) after 'changePage'. Because I don't see (this) coming back in your 'master.php'.

Comment: I'd switch out the inline click handlers for a jQuery `on` delegation

Comment: Also don't forget to add real page `href` to links, if you want them crawled by SE.

Comment: @fence I have created this as demo sturcutre.You need to call function on your menu link click. I use "this" keyword because we can identify which href wolud be click and we can chang respective .tpl file. You can check in changePage function we are fetching $(obj).data('page') which return page name of href click.

Comment: @HarshPatel I have tried your code but it's not passing the data from the content files into the 'fileContent section'. It only puts a # after my url.

Comment: Check in network tab of inspect elememt does it calling right file path or not otherwise debuge and change $("#fileContent").html(Filename) to remove # from href gives you menu url href="javascript:void(0)"

Comment: @HarshPatel that doesn't do anything, as far as I can see atleast.

Comment: have you include Jquery ??? If not then include j query check my edited question.

Comment: also check you are giving right file name and path at data-page="home.tpl" It definitely works. :)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is called AJAX(With Ajax, web applications can send data to and retrieve from a server asynchronously (in the background) without interfering with the display and behavior of the existing page.)

To use ajax u need Javascript to send the request to a PHP file that loads the smarty template that contains your main content and insert the html code back into the page:

```
<?php
//some-php-file.php
include("Smarty.class.php");
$smarty = new Smarty;
$smarty->display("main_content_part.tpl");
?>
```

```
//link on 'home' site
<a href="#" id="ajaxHomeBtn">Home</a>
```

```
//javascript(jquery) ajax request
$('#ajaxHomeBtn').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $.get("some-php-file.php", function(smarty_html_data) {
    $(".main-content").html(smarty_html_data);
  });
});
```

Comment: Please change that `<a href="javascript:void(0);"` the links should be accessible without JavaScript! Better to have the actual link and just prevent default behaviour.

Comment: AJAX is pretty new to me, I don't understand anything of this so I doubt I can implement that myself...

Comment: @fence Its easy dont worry. What the third part does is get the content of your smarty template(main content part) and insert it into the html tag with the class 'main-content'.

Comment: @b3wii I get that part, but what is smarty? I see: include("Smarty.class.php"); What should be in that php file then?

Comment: @fence You were talking about .tpl files which is usually used as Smarty file extension. If you dont use Smarty then you can ignore the first part and point the $.get to your php tpl file

Comment: @b3wii Well, each tpl file has more than 400 lines of code. Mostly html/javascript and a few php lines.

Comment: @fence Ok, create a php file "some-php-file.php" and add this <?php include('main_content_part.tpl'); ?>